# Upwards particle effect in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm getting started with After Effect and I want to make some simple music videos.

How can I achieve the subtle effect of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Fd5eAWvPDo&t=23) video which shows semi-transparent upwards particles in a loop?

Comment: Do you specifically want it to be a repeat or do you want to just have random particles drifting up and expanding and going away?  They are very different answers depending on which you want.

Comment: I think it would be more visually appealing with random particles drifting up and fading away.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer right now, but Particle Playground is the effect you want to look in to.  I'll try to do a write up if I get time, but my free time for answer writing has been pretty limited lately, so not sure when I'll be able to get to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you have time to write up an answer I'll be glad to give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous options for particles in AE, without needing any 3rd party plugins. For example the CC Particle Systems II effect which is included with AE CS and later. A PDF manual for the cycore effects (all the **CC-something** effects that are included with AE) are [here](http://cycorefx.com/downloads/cfx_hd_std/CycoreFX%20HD%201.8.1%20Manual.pdf)

If you add it to a layer you'll see this:

[image]

By default the effect produces particles exploding from a small spot, and they fall as if effected by gravity. We're going to change it to look more like what you posted.

[image]

[rendered version on YT](https://youtu.be/LDP9jy71_Fc)

First, open up the effects control window, and work though the settings.

Change the **producer** size. This is the area from which the particles are produced. We'll mke it the width of the comp, without making it any taller vertically. So the **Radius X** will be 1920 for a HD comp. You might also want to wind down the birth rate, to say something like 0.1. Since we're making the particles move more slowly we'll need to increase their **longevity**. 15-20 seconds might be in the ball park for gently drifting particles.

They're shooting out of the producer at this point, so we'll turn that off. You do this in the **Physics** section, using the **Animation** drop-down. This sets the *initial* motion for the particles. For a more interesting movement you might try ***twirly***. Twirly adds some random directional velocity, explosion adds velocity away from the producer, vortex makes them swirl around.

You probably want to turn the **Velocity** right down, maybe 0.1 or thereabouts.  For a gentle drift we'll turn **Gravity** right down, and make it negative. I ended up using -0.25, see how you go.

**Resistance** acts like friction, slowing the particles down from their initial velocity. A little bit is probably good, but if you want the particles to all have random velocity you can leave it quite low, like 1 or 2.

Play with the physics until you get it to look right. Reading the manual is a start, but fiddling with the controls to see how they work is the best way. Once you've got them drifting gently upwards you might want to move the **position** of the producer down below the bottom of the frame, e.g a bit more than 1080px. Also, if you want the particles to be there at the start of the comp, slide the start of the layer a few seconds before the start of the comp.

Next change the particle from the default line, to something else. I've chosen lens to create flat circles. Lens uses the original colour of the layer it's on, in this case it's a solid. You can muck around with colours, how the particle looks over time, and change the particle type here.

Remember you can also add more effects before or after the particles to change how they look, eg, blurs, colour correction, distortion, and so on. You can change the **opacity** of the layer as well as its **Blending Mode** to change how it interacts with other layers. Go nuts!

Here's a screenie of settings that produce a good gentle swirling particle effect. Don't just copy them though, they literally took me like five minutes, so you could easily refine them. Try twiddling the knobs, just to get a feel for what they do.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to replicate this in AE.

Comment: You should probably have a play with the other particle effects too. Particle playground, for e.g., despite being rather elderly has lots of scope for interesting motion, and the ability to use other layers to affect the motion of the particles.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin Particular would do this. It's by Trapcode.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate more on this? A full answer might be also useful for future users.

Comment: The information is already out there; Visit RedGiant's Trapcode's website:  http://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-particular/   They have all the information on the plugin; demo videos; tutorials; and I think you can even trial the plugin.  But essentially Particular is a particle generator- simple as that, with about 1000 parameters, making millions of possible "outcomes" in terms of what those particles do... From the particle itself, how they are emitted, taking into effect velocity, gravity; turbulence, etc. The videos on the Trapcode website are good, check youtube as well.

Comment: Is there a free alternative to this plugin?